# Redirect to a new page and scroll to a particular div on that new page

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone knows how to redirect to a new page and scroll to a particular div on that new page? Currently i'm using this, but it only scrolls in the same page. How to redirect using href and make it still actually working?

```
                <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                   data-target=".offer_container" class="header-nav-item"
                   onClick="document.getElementById('test').scrollIntoView();"
                >
                    Link
                </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Anchor Link. Set an id for the element/section you want to scroll to and link to this page with this id using hash, e.g.
section - `<h2 id="section_to_scroll">Title</h2>`

Link - `<a href="/new-page.html#section_to_scroll">Page</a>`

More info - https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html